# Change the default mpm-winnt on a Windows server

Tags: apache, apache2

I've been searching for hours without any luck - Is there a way to change to even/worker/prefork mpm on a Windows 2008 server, with Apache 2.4?

I couldn't find a way from httpd.conf (is there? That would be the easiest way for me)
Nor could I make it work with the command given in the Apache docs.

So, how can I get this done?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Doesn't it require a re-compile? http://serverfault.com/a/451503/186958

Comment: What do you mean? I can't even find where to tell it to use event/worker. Once i will I'll recompile, sure. And btw your link sort of proves that it wont work on windows, since it says "For unix based you can pick from .....". Am I right?

Comment: I think it is not a runtime option that is why you won't find it in httpd.conf. I have no further knowledge of Apache.

Comment: @rene so the only option is at compile time? If so, how?